# disabling DST time change or disabling zoneinfo file updates in Ubuntu

Tags: time, timezone, ubuntu-18.04

I am having Ubuntu 18 web server with MySQL database. We do calculation based on timezone.

i read that changing the sever timezone to GMT+_7 we can solve the DST time changes, as i tried it already and i was not getting my old data.

so my questions are below

1. How to disable DST time changes alone in Ubuntu 18, i couldn't find any options and searching also did not give me any results
2. How to stop updating the zonefile automatically in Ubuntu 18, if i can update the rules for the zone file.

Comment: if it's a server, why not use UTC?

Comment: yes, i know setting UTC was the actual design solution, but the server was set for America/Edmonton as the timezone, since the initial server setup we used a shared hosting. so now our whole data is there. so cannot change the server time to UTC, when i set the time to UTS, the mysql timestamp data got changed

Comment: Hi.  This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and belongs instead on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).  That said, you should probably *not* try to do this.  Applications and server configuration should be designed to handle DST if it is applicable - not try to disable it.  DST isn't a problem to be disabled - it's part of the reality of local time in a particular location.  Trying to "disable" it is likely to create even more problems.  Also, generally speaking, one should design such that the server's time zone will not affect an application at all.

Comment: i will post the same to serverFault https://serverfault.com/questions/1057386/disabling-dst-time-change-or-disabling-zoneinfo-file-updates-in-ubuntu